# How to do string replace in Xml format string

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have a xml format string stored in a database which is as below

First one

```
<Query name="test">    <Description />    
<Columns>      

<Column caption="Activities Name" sorting="None" sortIndex="-1">        
    <Expr class="ENTATTR" id="Activities.ActivityDescription" />      
</Column>      

<Column caption="Activities Group" sorting="None" sortIndex="-1">        
<Expr class="ENTATTR" id="{Activity Groups}.ActivityGroupDescription" />      
</Column>    

</Columns>    

<JustSortedColumns />    

<Conditions linking="All" />  
</Query>
```

In another table, the following xml has stored.

second one

```
<Columns>      

<Column caption="Activities Note" sorting="None" sortIndex="-1">        
    <Expr class="ENTATTR" id="Activities.Notes" />      
</Column>      

<Column caption="Activities Group" sorting="None" sortIndex="-1">        
<Expr class="ENTATTR" id="{Activity Groups}.ActivityGroupDescription" />      
</Column>    

</Columns>
```

I need to replace string between `'<columns>'` and `'</columns>'` from second one to first one. so after replacement:

First one string must be as below:

```
    <Query name="test">    <Description />    
<Columns>      

    <Column caption="Activities Note" sorting="None" sortIndex="-1">        
        <Expr class="ENTATTR" id="Activities.Notes" />      
    </Column>      

    <Column caption="Activities Group" sorting="None" sortIndex="-1">        
    <Expr class="ENTATTR" id="{Activity Groups}.ActivityGroupDescription" />      
    </Column>    

</Columns>     

<JustSortedColumns />   

<Conditions linking="All" />  
</Query>
```

Comment: Editing XML with `String.Replace`/`Concat` is generally bad idea. Consider not doing it. Also consider editing your post with code that you've tried and have problem with...

Comment: Always use an XML API to edit XML. Something like LINQ to XML.

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ to XML:

Test setup code:

```
var s1 = @"<Query name=""test"">    <Description />    
<Columns>      

<Column caption=""Activities Name"" sorting=""None"" sortIndex=""-1"">        
    <Expr class=""ENTATTR"" id=""Activities.ActivityDescription"" />      
</Column>      

<Column caption=""Activities Group"" sorting=""None"" sortIndex=""-1"">        
<Expr class=""ENTATTR"" id=""{Activity Groups}.ActivityGroupDescription"" />      
</Column>    

</Columns>    

<JustSortedColumns />    

<Conditions linking=""All"" />  
</Query>";
var s2 = @"<Columns>      

<Column caption=""Activities Note"" sorting=""None"" sortIndex=""-1"">        
    <Expr class=""ENTATTR"" id=""Activities.Notes"" />      
</Column>      

<Column caption=""Activities Group"" sorting=""None"" sortIndex=""-1"">        
<Expr class=""ENTATTR"" id=""{Activity Groups}.ActivityGroupDescription"" />      
</Column>    

</Columns>  ";
```

Actual code:

```
var x1 = XElement.Parse(s1);
var x2 = XElement.Parse(s2);

x1.Descendants("Columns").Single()
    .ReplaceAll(x2.Descendants("Column"));
var result = x1.ToString();
```